# How to properly test if the correct Fragment is being displayed with Espresso?

Tags: android, unit-testing, fragment, android-espresso

I'm currently using the fragments layout id. If the layout is displayed, the test passes. But I had to add ids to every fragment layout in order to do this (got 3 unique fragments). The resulting code is the following:

```
 @Test
fun popularButtonShowsRightFragment() {
    onView(withId(R.id.popular)).perform(click())

    onView(withId(R.id.popularServicesLayout))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    onView(withId(R.id.myServicesLayout))
            .check(doesNotExist())
    onView(withId(R.id.standardServicesLayout))
            .check(doesNotExist())
}
```

So when I press `R.id.popular` I know that the Popular Fragment is being displayed, and the others are not. Is there any cleaner way to do this? I want to avoid adding ids to every fragment layout.

Maybe I could use an existing id inside the layout, but I still think I could use a cleaner way. By the way, I'm using a `FrameLayout` as my `Fragment` container.